# 'MsoFileType' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Core'

Tags: .net, vb.net, vsto, office-interop

I'm not a beginner but this one apparently doesn't have any solution. I've got an add-in that references both Word and Excel Object Libraries. I get the following error on a few enumerations

```
'MsoFileType' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Core'.
```

I have tried fully qualifying enumeration, to no avail. I have tried to use named imports too, without any success. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What code do you have now?

Comment: The code is simply `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.FileSearch.FileType = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoFileType.msoFileTypeWordDocuments`. That shouldn't have any role in it though.